# jQuery UI slider: Overlaying the range image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm building a vertical range slider:

[image]

It's going to be awesome.

Implemented with jQuery UI 1.8, though, I've only come this far:

[image]

I've wrapped the slider in a container which has `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to keep the slider's range element in place.

Without the container, the range will overlap the background:

[image]

Any good solutions?

Here's some code, if necessary:

LESS-code:

```
    /*
     * Center the slider by wrapping it in a container
     */
    .slider-container {
        text-align: center;

        /*
         * Another container that holds the actual background of the slider,
         * with padding to make sure the handle doesn't go outside of the background.
         */
        .slider-bg {
            background: transparent url('/static/images/slider_bg.png') 0% 0%;
            height: 235px;
            width: 28px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            margin: 0 auto;

            /*
             * The actual element holding the slide handler
             */
            .ui-slider {
                height: 234px;
                width: 28px;
                background: none;

                // Overrides
                .border-radius(0 0 0 0);
                border: 0;

                .ui-slider-handle {
                    width: 28px;
                    height: 29px;

                    background: transparent url('/static/images/slider_handle.png') 0% 0%;

                    // Overrides
                    left: 0;
                    .border-radius(0 0 0 0);
                    border: 0;
                }

                .ui-slider-range {
                    width: 28px;
                    background: transparent url('/static/images/slider_range.png') 0% 0%;
                    padding-bottom: 13px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

JS:

```
$('div.slider').slider({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    animate: 'true',
    range: 'min',
    slide: function (event, ui) {
    }
});
```

Comment: don't you want to show us your code?

Comment: wasn't sure it was necessary. updated.

Comment: Ah crap, the images I linked to had the wrong URL. I've uploaded them now instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make it this way:

```
/* Corner radius */
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 14px; border-top-left-radius: 14px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px; -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 14px; border-top-right-radius: 14px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px; -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px; border-bottom-left-radius: 14px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px; -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px; border-bottom-right-radius: 14px; }
```

And UI widget header:

```
.ui-widget-header
{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    background: #33CCFF url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_50_dddddd_1x100.png) repeat-x 50% 50%;
    color: #444444;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}
```

Widget Content:

```
.ui-widget-content {background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #444444; }
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwsJD/26/) for you

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer! Unfortunately, relying on border-radius won't work in IE. I could always use CSS3 PIE, but I don't think I'll end up with the same result as if I'm using an image. I'll consider it, thanks. Here's to hoping for a cross-browser solution!

Comment: Also, you do know that you don't have to repeat the top-left-radius and top-right-radius etc, as you do in the demo? `border-radius: 14px` would be sufficient (plus all the vendor prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

```
NameError: .border-radius is undefined on line 27, column 17:

26                 
27                 .border-radius(0 0 0 0);
28                 border: 0;
```

Hope it helps